# Customising ToggleButton state images using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently using the XAML below to change the image on a toggle button for each state.  How can I define a template or style that will allow me to define the images that are to be used in the button definition such that I don't have to repeat everything below for each button. Is this even possible ?

Ideally I would like to define a template with properties such as 'checkedImage', 'uncheckedImage' and then set these properties in the button definition in Designer.

I would also like the button to prevent the display of any other states or animations but I can't seem to prevent the background changing when the button is selected or when there is a mouseover.  Are there some additional states that I don't have defined below?

Sample code (XAML, C#) for the style or template and for the actual toggle button definition would be appreciated.  Also any references to 'simple' samples and explanations would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:  Update with my latest attempt...

This almost works - the correct image never gets displayed when the button is Checked.  Any ideas what I am missing here?

```
<Style x:Key="ImgToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid x:Name="GD" Background="White">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="CP" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="GD" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ThemeSolidColorBrushBlue}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="GD" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                     </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                       <!-- Nothing so we have no change-->

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the button definition

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="allTestsToggleButton"  Tag="Asset/AllTestsButton_1.png" Style="{DynamicResource ImgToggleButton}" ClickMode="Press" Checked="allTestsToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="allTestsToggleButton_Unchecked"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    <ToggleButton.Content>
        <Image Source="Assets/AllTestsButton_0.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </ToggleButton.Content>
</ToggleButton>
```

Setting `TargetName="CP"` does not work either

```
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="CP" Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="GD" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ThemeSolidColorBrushBlue}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="GD" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                 </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                   <!-- Nothing so we have no change-->

                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update1**

You can use this style for multiple button with different images and I have used tag for storing image for checked state true and use templatebinding for default look i.e state=false

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="imag1" UriSource="image1.jpg"></BitmapImage>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="imag2" UriSource="path.jpg"></BitmapImage>


    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="GD" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GD" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}"></ImageBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<ToggleButton x:Name="sampleTestToggleButton"  Tag="{StaticResource imag2}"  ClickMode="Press"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"  BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent">
    <ToggleButton.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource imag1}"></ImageBrush>
    </ToggleButton.Background>
</ToggleButton>
```

**Update2**:
Hope this helps.Run this code separately.It is working fine here.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ImgToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="GD" Background="White">
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger  Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}"></Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="GD" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!-- Nothing so we have no change-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ToggleButton x:Name="allTestsToggleButton" Content="imag2.jpg" Tag="imag1.jpg" Style="{DynamicResource ImgToggleButton}" ClickMode="Press"   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
```

Comment: I still don't get this - how would I use this for other buttons which require their own images for each state

Comment: Is it possible to define a template with properties 'checkedImage', 'uncheckedImage' and then set these properties when you define the button in Designer

Comment: OK well that's what I was trying to ask - will update my question

Comment: @Duncan Groenewald: see my answer, working with Images in Templates in WPF it's  Winforms style. Use powerful vector graphics system of WPF.

Comment: @HeenaPatil - would you care to elaborate on how I would go about doing this

Comment: Looks promising, what is 'Tag' that you are using ?  Can I define 'TagC' and 'TagU' in a similar manner ?  I tried but get an error.

Comment: No u cant use Tagc and TagU.Tag is property for controls.it is empty property and u can store any value to it.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The other issue is that I don't want to set the background to the image, I need to set the Content to the image and the background gets set to the same colour as the background of the image (a defined shade of blue) to prevent the bitmap image from being scaled to fit the button size. Still I am assuming I can use the same approach for setting the Content

Comment: Right so how would I define my own properties ?  In this case I could get away with using just Tag and the default background.

Comment: @HeenaPatil you solution is so close but the is line is not returning the filename 
`<Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>`
If I hardcode the same filename in the template it works beautifully.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Please see update in answer.Hope this helps

Comment: @HeenaPatil brilliant, thanks - the only issue now is that in the Designer the image does not get shown but I can live with that.  I still don't know if I understand how the template definition works so if you have any references to good tutorials please post them as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need for the ability to use vector graphics in WPF. In this case, to use the `Path`, where in `Data` to the specified coordinates on which the object is drawn [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx).

Advantages:

- Do not store it in the files, smaller size
- Do not store this files in Resources
- Dynamically changing color, size and the whole shape

The Minuses, in my opinion:

- You can not always find the right `Data` for the `Path`

About minus: There are special sites, like [`www.modernuiicons.com`](http://modernuiicons.com/) and utilities for converting the image to `Data`. For converting `Image` to Vector graphics (Path) use [`Inkscape`](http://inkscape.org), him free and very useful. For more information see this link:

[`Vectorize Bitmaps to XAML using Potrace and Inkscape`](http://blog.tiaan.com/link/2009/02/21/vectorize-bitmaps-to-xaml-using-potrace-inkscape)

**`Example`**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="styleCustomCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Path x:Name="MyPin" Width="18" Height="18" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000"
                              Data="F1 M 56.1355,32.5475L 43.4466,19.8526C 42.7886,20.4988 42.298,21.2123 41.9749,21.9932C 41.6519,22.7741 41.4903,23.5729 41.4903,24.3895C 41.4903,25.1942 41.6529,25.987 41.9779,26.7679L 34.0577,34.6821C 33.3918,34.3372 32.6991,34.0776 31.9796,33.9032C 31.2601,33.7288 30.5298,33.6415 29.7885,33.6415C 28.623,33.6415 27.4953,33.8526 26.4052,34.2748C 25.315,34.697 24.3419,35.3342 23.4856,36.1865L 30.2344,42.9174L 25.9027,47.9032L 22.6532,51.8425L 20.5988,54.5836C 20.1212,55.2892 19.8823,55.753 19.8823,55.975L 19.8645,56.0701L 19.9002,56.088L 19.9002,56.1474L 19.9358,56.1058L 20.0131,56.1236C 20.2351,56.1236 20.6989,55.8888 21.4045,55.419L 24.1457,53.3765L 28.0849,50.1151L 33.0945,45.7775L 39.8016,52.5025C 40.6579,51.6462 41.2961,50.6731 41.7163,49.5829C 42.1365,48.4928 42.3466,47.367 42.3466,46.2056C 42.3466,45.4603 42.2603,44.729 42.0879,44.0115C 41.9155,43.294 41.6548,42.6003 41.3069,41.9304L 49.2202,34.0161C 50.0011,34.3372 50.7939,34.4978 51.5986,34.4978C 52.4192,34.4978 53.2189,34.3362 53.9979,34.0132C 54.7768,33.6901 55.4894,33.2015 56.1355,32.5475 Z "/>

                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="MyPin" Property="Data" Value="F1 M 32.3691,30.2225L 33.2253,29.3901L 15.361,11.5258C 13.9814,12.7067 12.6951,13.9936 11.5148,15.3738L 26.6252,30.4842C 27.743,30.1631 28.8767,30.0025 30.0263,30.0025C 30.8191,30.0025 31.6,30.0759 32.3691,30.2225 Z M 45.5039,49.3629L 60.6292,64.4826C 62.0123,63.2996 63.3017,62.0101 64.4846,60.6268L 46.6218,42.7866L 45.7834,43.619L 45.9439,44.7726L 45.9915,45.9261L 45.8785,47.6713L 45.5039,49.3629 Z M 56.1355,32.5475L 43.4466,19.8526C 42.7886,20.4987 42.298,21.2123 41.9749,21.9932C 41.6519,22.7741 41.4903,23.5729 41.4903,24.3895C 41.4903,25.1942 41.6529,25.987 41.9779,26.7679L 34.0577,34.6821C 33.3918,34.3372 32.6991,34.0776 31.9796,33.9032C 31.2601,33.7288 30.5298,33.6415 29.7885,33.6415C 28.623,33.6415 27.4953,33.8526 26.4052,34.2748C 25.315,34.697 24.3419,35.3342 23.4856,36.1865L 30.2344,42.9174L 25.9027,47.9032L 22.6532,51.8425L 20.5988,54.5836C 20.1212,55.2892 19.8823,55.753 19.8823,55.975L 19.8645,56.0701L 19.9002,56.0879L 19.9002,56.1474L 19.9358,56.1058L 20.0131,56.1236C 20.2351,56.1236 20.6989,55.8888 21.4045,55.419L 24.1457,53.3765L 28.0849,50.1151L 33.0945,45.7775L 39.8016,52.5025C 40.6579,51.6462 41.2961,50.6731 41.7163,49.5829C 42.1365,48.4928 42.3466,47.367 42.3466,46.2056C 42.3466,45.4603 42.2603,44.729 42.0879,44.0115C 41.9155,43.294 41.6548,42.6003 41.306,41.9304L 49.2202,34.0161C 50.0011,34.3372 50.7939,34.4978 51.5986,34.4978C 52.4192,34.4978 53.219,34.3362 53.9979,34.0132C 54.7768,33.6901 55.4894,33.2015 56.1355,32.5475 Z " />
                            <Setter TargetName="MyPin" Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <CheckBox Height="35"
              Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
              Content="MySolution1" />

    <CheckBox Height="35"
              Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBox}" 
              Content="MySolution2" />
</StackPanel>
```

**`Output`**

[image]

Comment: I don't need vector graphics, I am using *.png files. I am totally confused as to how this answers my question.

Comment: @Duncan Groenewald: Well, I think you can justify why you do not want to work with vector graphics in WPF? If you do not work, then you can at least try, that would understand how it convenient than working with images.